# How do I remove black bars on top and bottom of my display?

Tags: monitor

I have a problem with my ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It shows my Samsung Electric Company 17'' strange. It is not centered. I have a black space up and right.

The pictures will explain better my problem:

[image: screenshot]

---

This is what `xrandr` shows:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: It is mostly a problem with your monitor. Try to "Auto Adjust" (or manually adjust) your screen or maybe xrandr --auto can help...

Comment: With Auto Adjust was much worse but I unplugged the monitor and Auto Adjust again and came back to normal. It is strange that this is happening only when I play games. Thank you mondjunge

Comment: When playing games, it happens that the game you play set its own resolution. Sometimes this makes problems, but I was always able to cope with these problems, either by auto-adjusting or setting a more adequate resolution in game options. If possible try to use DVI or HDMI, these work better than the old vga standard, in regards of adjusting the screen correctly.